# EF One-to-many Foreign Keys without child navigation properties

Tags: c#, entity-framework, foreign-keys, code-first

Using code-first Entity Framework and .NET 4, I'm trying to create a one-to-many relationship between parents to children:

```cs
public class Parent
{
    [Key]
    public int ParentId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string ParentName { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Child> Children { get; set; }
}

public class Child
{
    [Key]
    public int ChildId { get;  set; }
    [ForeignKey]
    public int ParentId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string ChildName { get; set; }
}
```

As pointed out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8452725/entity-framework-map-foreign-key-without-navigation-property/8455916#8455916), in order for foreign key relationship to carry into the database, the actual objects must be linked, not just their IDs. The normal way to do this if for a child to contain a reference to its parent ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5543702/1180926)).

But how do I enforce foreign keys in *my* implementation, which is the other way around (parent referencing children)?

Comment: You mean `public class Child` instead of `public class AddressMatch`, right?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

First of all: You cannot use `IEnumerable<T>` for a collection navigation property. EF will just ignore this property. Use `ICollection<T>` instead.

When you have changed this, in your particular example you don't need to do anything because the foreign key property name follows the convention (name of primary key `ParentId` in principal entity `Parent`) so that EF will detect a required one-to-many relationship between `Parent` and `Child` automatically.

If you had another "unconventional" FK property name you still could define such a mapping with Fluent API, for example:

```
public class Child
{
    [Key]
    public int ChildId { get;  set; }

    public int SomeOtherId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string ChildName { get; set; }
}
```

Mapping:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Parent>()
    .HasMany(p => p.Children)
    .WithRequired()
    .HasForeignKey(c => c.SomeOtherId);
```

As far as I can tell it is not possible to define this relationship with data annotations. Usage of the `[ForeignKey]` attribute requires a navigation property in the dependent entity where the foreign key property is in.