# Fluent API - One 2 Many Relationship

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-fluent-api

I have two Entities i.e. Employee and Company. Both of these can have one or many addresses. **As Guid is always unique, so i want to use Guid in Employee and Company as a foreign key in Address.** 

That's there can be multiple entries in Address for Employee and Guid of Employee will be in Guid Field of Address.
In the same way, There can be multiple addresses for a company as well. And Guid of Company will be in Guid of Address.

Can you please help me how to configure relationship b/w Employee-Address and Company-Address using Fluent APIs

```
public class Employee
{
    public int EmployeeId;
    public Guid Guid;
    .
    .
    .
    public ICollection<Address> Addresses;
}

public class Company
{
    public int CompanyId;
    public Guid Guid;
    .
    .
    .
    public ICollection<Address> Addresses;
}

public class Address
{
    public int AddressId
    public Guid Guid; // Guid from Employee or Company
    .
    .
    . // Should here be Navigation to Employee/Company as well?


}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure If I've understood your problem. Do you want two simple 1:N relations like these?:

```
Emplyee 1:N Adress
Company 1:N Adress
```

If this is the case, you should have this model:

```
public class Employee
{
    public int EmployeeId { get; set; };
    // ...
    public virutal ICollection<Address> Addresses { get; set; };
}

public class Company
{
    public int CompanyId { get; set; };
    // ...
    public ICollection<Address> Addresses { get; set; };
}

public class Address
{
    public int AddressId { get; set; };
    public int? EmployeeId { get; set; };
    public int? CompanyId { get; set; };
    // ...
    public virtual Employee Employee { get; set; };
    public virtual Company Company { get; set; };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Setup you entities like

```
public class Employee
{
    //no need of following line. just use the GUID as Employee id
    //public int EmployeeId;  
    public Guid EmployeeId;
    .
    .
    .
    public ICollection<Address> Addresses;
}

public class Company
{
    public int CompanyId;//no need of this line, use guid as company id
    public Guid CompanyId;
    .
    .
    .
    public ICollection<Address> Addresses;
}

public class Address
{
    public int AddressId
    public Guid OwnerId; // Guid from Employee or Company
    .
    .
    //don't add Navigation to Employee/Company


}
```

then in fluent API, do what [slauma](https://stackoverflow.com/users/270591/slauma) has suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11350517/ef-one-to-many-foreign-keys-without-child-navigation-properties).

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Company>()
.HasMany(c => c.Addresses)
.WithRequired()
.HasForeignKey(a => a.OwnerId);

modelBuilder.Entity<Employee>()
.HasMany(c => c.Addresses)
.WithRequired()
.HasForeignKey(a => a.OwnerId);
```